Geometry nodes, curve tilt problem
when i apply thickness to the curve, it creates an unexpected rotation/tilt .

the result i want:

Geometry nodes:



It's 0° tilt, but related to what? You need to set the base normal, and you have two options for that: calculated from the 'shape' of the curve in such a way to minimize twisting, or just always pointing up, and it seems you want the latter:

If neither option works for you, you could use this answer as a starting point to developing your own tilt calculation:
Trimming start of the curve geometry nodes without altering tilt

thank u, I didn't know about this node.
